# Is it possible to append to a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, rendering

I have a long video, and I want to append another short video at the end, sort of like credits, but I need to do this for many videos so I don't want to reencode them. Is it possible to just append this second video to the end

Comment: Yes, if some important stream parameters match: video codec and profile, resolution, pixel format. audio codec and profile, sampling rate, channel count. You can use the concat demuxer: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer

Comment: Thanks that's good to know, I will use the same program to render them so this will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you, don't underestimate the similar parameters needed. If fps (set with -r), audio sample rate (-ar), codecs, resolution and sar (if you don't want stretching) (https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/how-do-i-change-frame-size-preserving-width-using-ffmpeg), aren't the same... you'll be fuming for hours until you find out they were the problem.